# I am little bit confuse in this Builder Design pattern code of java

Tags: java

I Just want to understand what is happening in this line of the code 
`Phone ph=new PhoneBuilder().setOs("android").setRam("2").get();` and how this line is working. and why we assigning two object in 'Phone ph' reference variable because PhoneBuilder class method returning its object. And sorry for my bad English.

```
public class MakePhone {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       Phone ph=new PhoneBuilder().setOs("android").setRam("2").get();
       System.out.println(ph);

    }
}


public class Phone {
        String os,ram,storage,processor;


        public Phone(String os, String ram, String storage, String processor){
            this.os=os;
            this.ram=ram;
            this.storage=storage;
            this.processor=processor;
        }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Os"+os+",Ram"+ram+",Storage"+storage+"Processor"+"" ;
    }
}

public class PhoneBuilder {
    String os,ram,storage,processor;

    public PhoneBuilder setOs(String os) {
        this.os = os;
        return this;
    }

    public PhoneBuilder setRam(String ram) {
        this.ram = ram;
        return this;
    }

    public PhoneBuilder setStorage(String storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
        System.out.println(this);
        return this;
    }

    public PhoneBuilder setProcessor(String processor) {
        this.processor = processor;
        return this;
    }
    public Phone get(){
        return new Phone(os, ram, storage, processor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the builder line of code in question:

```
Phone ph = new PhoneBuilder()
    .setOs("android")         // sets the OS and returns a reference to the builder
    .setRam("2")              // sets the RAM and also returns a reference
    .get();                   // calls the constructor for a Phone
```

We can see that the builder pattern works by first populating a `PhoneBuilder` POJO object with all the attributes with which we want to create a `Phone` object.  We do so in a compact way via method chaining, which works because each builder setter method returns a reference to the same builder object.  Then, at the end, we invoke `get()` which creates a new `Phone` instance.

The builder pattern is useful where a Java class might have many different types of potential constructors.  Rather than catering to this requirement by actually creating many different constructors, which could become a maintenance nightmare, with the builder pattern we in theory just need a single contructor invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the builder line of code in question:

```java
Phone ph = new PhoneBuilder()
    .setOs("android")         // sets the OS and returns a reference to the builder
    .setRam("2")              // sets the RAM and also returns a reference
    .get();                   // calls the constructor for a Phone
```

it's equal to the code below:

```java
PhoneBuilder builder = new PhoneBuilder()
builder.setOs("android")
builder.setRam("2")
Phone ph = new Phone(builder.os,builder.ram,builder.storage,builder.processor);
```

The goodness of the builder pattern was that all the process of setting value to phone was completed at once, so it can avoid a lot of thread safe problems.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Phone ph = new PhoneBuilder()
    .setOs("android")
    .setRam("2")
    .get();
```

This block of code utilizes a **builder pattern**, one of the [creational patterns](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/creational-patterns) of the gang of four design patterns.

It is a very neat way of constructing complex objects step by step typically used when there's need to build different immutable objects using the same object building process.

Consider the following problem, a citation from [refactoring.guru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder):

> Imagine a complex object that requires laborious, step-by-step
>   initialization of many fields and nested objects. Such initialization
>   code is usually buried inside a monstrous constructor with lots of
>   parameters. Or even worse: scattered all over the client code.

The builder pattern suggests that you extract the object construction code out of its own class and move it to separate objects called builders.

Taking the example of the code in the question, object construction code has been separated out of the `Phone` class into the `PhoneBuilder` class.

The `PhoneBuilder` class uses public setter methods (i.e. `setOs(String os)`, `setRam(String ram)`, `setStorage(String storage)`, `setProcessor(String processor)`) to set various attributes of the `Phone` POJO.

Each of the setters returns the same `Phone` instance via the `this` pointer hence method chaining is possible i.e:

```java
Phone ph = new PhoneBuilder().setOs("android").setRam("2").get();
```

The `get()` method initializes and returns a `Phone` instance with the attributes the builder class has. It's thus called as the last method in the chain.

You can read more about the builder pattern (and other design patterns) [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder).
Find other examples on the pattern [here](https://github.com/kwahome/gof-patterns-java/tree/master/src/main/java/io/github/kwahome/creational/builder).